# Shenandoah GC pause time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, shenandoah

I am using Shenandoah GC and using Java 8

`"-XX:+UseShenandoahGC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:ShenandoahGCHeuristics=compact -XX:+ClassUnloadingWithConcurrentMark -Xloggc:/LOGS/CAS/gclog -XX:ShenandoahAllocationThreshold=20"`

with this average pause time is 8 ms but max pause time is 160 ms. I dont want pause time to go beyond 25 ms. Is there any parameter to set which ensures that pause time shouldnt be go beyond it ?

Please help and suggest

Comment: Do you get different pause times with `-XX:ShenandoahGCHeuristics=aggressive`? (Do not use that for production) Does `-XX:-ShenandoahDegeneratedGC` change anything?

Comment: If `-XX:ShenandoahGCHeuristics=aggressive` does "help", you might want to try reducing the `-XX:ShenandoahAllocationThreshold` (with `-XX:ShenandoahGCHeuristics=compact`). Also, did you try removing options like `-XX:+ClassUnloadingWithConcurrentMark` and checking the results? While I don't know about specific options for ensuring pause times lower than a specific value, you might be able to do other tweaks (or try using a newer Java version).

Comment: You should post some log excerpts that show long pause events.

Comment: "with this average pause time is 8 ms but max pause time is 160 ms", where are the verbose logs?